# Read several csv files in r and merge them by 1st column(left join)?

Tags: r, csv

I have tens of csv files I want just to read in r the 2nd and 3rd columns of each file and then merge them by the 1st column named gene together while naming each column by its filename
this is the columns I want to read

rep.B0.t1month

```
         gene             count
 SPAP11E10.01             12608
  SPAC20G8.02              1218
 SPBC23G7.12c             10306
  SPBC17G9.09              8635
 SPAC1639.02c              5909
 SPCC1739.08c              5700
  SPCC569.08c              5283
```

rep.A0.t1month

```
           gene            counts
       SPAC343.09             19722.      
     SPAP11E10.01             15958
      SPAC20G8.02             13849
     SPBC32F12.09             11276
     SPBC23G7.12c              9054
       SPBC3F6.05              7703
     SPBPB8B6.04c              6553
```

---

I want to end up having something like but for tens of files

```
            gene   rep.A0.t1month   rep.B0.t1month
      SPAC20G8.02        12100         4508
               wt         9825         2625
     SPAP11E10.01         8960         2904
     SPBC32F12.09         8302         3956
     SPBC23G7.12c         7636         1708
      SPCC1919.01         6568         1950
      SPCC4G3.05c         6486         3682
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [Questions should be reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** for the different data structure.

Previously, you said *"1st and 3rd column"*, now it is a two-column table; using the subsetting I originally suggested of `[,c(1,3)]` makes no sense if your data only has two columns. Currently your question reads *"2nd and 3rd columns"* but still your data only has two columns, so I'm going to honor your premise of columns and names and ignore the rest.

When I create two files as you provided above, I can run:

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = 1L, all = TRUE),
       lapply(list.files(pattern = "^rep", full.names = TRUE),
              function(fn) {
                x <- read.table(fn, header = TRUE)
                names(x)[2] <- basename(fn)
                x
              }))
#            gene rep.A0.t1month rep.B0.t1month
# 1  SPAC1639.02c             NA           5909
# 2   SPAC20G8.02          13849           1218
# 3    SPAC343.09          19722             NA
# 4  SPAP11E10.01          15958          12608
# 5   SPBC17G9.09             NA           8635
# 6  SPBC23G7.12c           9054          10306
# 7  SPBC32F12.09          11276             NA
# 8    SPBC3F6.05           7703             NA
# 9  SPBPB8B6.04c           6553             NA
# 10 SPCC1739.08c             NA           5700
# 11  SPCC569.08c             NA           5283
```

I don't know about your expected output, since your sample data is inconsistent and has unmatched `gene` values. I hope this is helpful.

Here I did a full-join, but you can change it to a left-join by changing `all=TRUE` to `all.x=TRUE`.

---

Original code, for reference.

```r
files <- list.files("path", pattern = "csv$", full.names = TRUE)
out <- Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a, b, by = 1L), lapply(files, function(fn) {
  x <- read.csv(fn)[,c(1,3)]
  names(x)[2] <- basename(fn)
  x
}))
```

Comment: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'Reduce': 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
Called from: h(simpleError(msg, call))

Comment: I need them to be left_join

Comment: Your data structure has changed, I updated my question.

Comment: HEllo sorry about changing itt

Comment: The table I show  that has 2 column is the 2 column I want to include that column 2 and 3 and this table is sooo long about 3000 gene i just show the head of it